# How is the first variation formula applied here?

Tags: differential-geometry

Regarding Lemma 9.3 (page 262) in this paper by [Huisken](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-20/issue-1/Flow-by-mean-curvature-of-convex-surfaces-into-spheres/10.4310/jdg/1214438998.full), I have two questions.

1. It is said
   $$\vert \tilde{M}_{\tilde t} \vert = \frac{1}{n}\int \tilde H (\tilde F \tilde \nu) d\mu$$ follows from the 1st variation formula.

I can only recognize the integral is the variation of area functional, but I don't know how to derive this equation from the 1st variation formula.

2. Why the enclosed volume $\tilde V$ can be estimated by ball of radius $(\varepsilon \tilde H_{\text{min}})^{-1}$, knowing its second fundamental form $\tilde h_{ij} \geq \varepsilon \tilde H_{\text{max}}\tilde g_{ij}$ ? This is reasonable on an intuitive level, but how can I write down an explicit proof ?

Thanks